# How to write to the sector of an img floppy disk of my choice

Tags: assembly, x86, interrupt, x86-16

How do I put a program in a sector of my choice on a img floopy disk.

I'm trying to do this with assembler and virtualbox with Int 13/AH=03h: http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0608.htm

but it does not work on all sectors, only on the first.

For example with CHS addressing I can write to sector: 0 / 0 / 1 up to sector: 0 / 0 / 9, but when I want to write to sector: 0 / 0 / 10 I just can't , Why ?

And I can even less do it on a head or a different cylinder when precisely I want to do it on cylinders and heads other than the first, for information I can access the sectors in question in reading when I cannot do in writing.

I've tried using int 26 but with no success, I've even looked for a way to be able to pad sectors outside of assembler, manually on my windows but haven't found anything I can get to to understand.

Comment: Make sure your image file is large enough and that you are using the correct geometry. What error do you get? Show your code.

Comment: Thank you, it was the size of the image file that blocked me